# Blob Image not coverting into base64

Tags: php, mysql, base64, blob

Hii all i am trying to convert blog string into base64 but i am unable to do that please guys help me to get out from it..

this is my Blob string

```
    $blob="blob:4cfaa6d2-3712-4986-98d7-bd8747d26f8b";
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($blob);
    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($image, null, 80);
    $imagedata = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $img=base64_encode($imagedata);
```

and mysql insert query goes here for insert this base_64 encoded image

and i am getting this "error Data is not in a recognized format"

Please help me guys..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I don't think the string `blob:` followed by a GUID is valid image data in any of the formats supported by PHP. Where did you get the idea you can just pass that to `imagecreatefromstring`?

Comment: check, if($image!== FALSE) { echo "Success"; } else { echo "fail"; exit(); } before encoding...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen then what should i do ?? i am getting this blob: from canvas and svg through.. can you give me some idea please ??

Comment: @Renku its going in else condition return false.. and getting exit..

Comment: @Mohammad: Try to find out how to get *actual* image data from "canvas and svg". Anything that short isn't going to be able to encode much of an image anyways.

Comment: i guess i am getting the real path from svg because when i insert the code of blob: on same page into image source i am able to see that image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short string "blob:4cfaa6d2-3712-4986-98d7-bd8747d26f8b" is just a UUID your browser generated to identify a dynamically generated image. Transmitting this ridiculously short string to the server will definitely not transmit the image.

Instead, in your JavaScript, you need to create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object, append the Blob to it, and then POST the FormData object to the server using XMLHttpRequest. The image should arrive at the server as a normal [file upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). See [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) on MDN for example code.